# Where is it better to place the drawing of the bezier mask in the tableview cell

Tags: uitableview, tableview, cell, draw, bezier

can you please advise

I make chat like in tinder using tableViewCell
In a cell I have a MessageBuble - Uiview
And every time I calculate the appropriate width for the label and crop the MessageBuble with rounded ends

The problem is that if I specify a static View cropping constant everything works ok, but as soon as I calculate the ideal label width everything goes wrong
The first time everything works ok, but as the table is reloaded everything collapses

In MessageBuble I crop View in Draw method
There is a label with a constant height equal to the height of the cells
The width is also constant.
Next, I pass the text and font to the label and calculate the width of the text, if it fits on one line, then I cut the MessageView to width

1. In the photo there are cells with a standard cropping constant
   Everything works perfectly on them, no matter how many times the TableView is reloaded
2. The video shows that after reloading the TableView, the cells change their size, although the Draw method is called only for the last cell[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7kMQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78UEj.gif)

My class testView in which i draw the bezier path

class testView: UIView {

```
var currentUser = Bool()
var perfectWidthLabel = CGFloat()
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 45))


override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if currentUser {
        label.frame.size.width = self.frame.width - 37
    }else {
        label.frame.size.width = self.frame.size.width - 20
    }
    var indentFromLeft: CGFloat = 0
    var indentFromRight: CGFloat = 0
    
    if self.frame.height < 55 {
        indentFromLeft =  self.frame.width  - label.intrinsicContentSize.width - 37
        indentFromRight =  self.frame.width  - label.intrinsicContentSize.width - 20
    }
    
    var maskPath = UIBezierPath()
    
    if currentUser {
        
        var leftRadius = self.frame.height / 2
        if self.frame.height > 55 {
            leftRadius = self.frame.height / 3
        }
        let topLeftRadius = CGSize(width: leftRadius, height: leftRadius)
        let topRightRadius = CGSize(width: 23, height: 23)
        let bottomLeftRadius = CGSize(width: leftRadius, height: leftRadius)
        let bottomRightRadius = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        
        maskPath = UIBezierPath(shouldRoundRect: bounds, topLeftRadius: topLeftRadius, topRightRadius: topRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius: bottomLeftRadius, bottomRightRadius: bottomRightRadius, indentFromLeft: indentFromLeft, indentFromRight: 0)
    }
    else {
        var rightRadius = self.frame.height / 2
        if self.frame.height > 55 {
            rightRadius = self.frame.height / 3
        }
        let topLeftRadius = CGSize(width: 23, height: 23)
        let topRightRadius = CGSize(width: rightRadius, height: rightRadius)
        let bottomLeftRadius = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        let bottomRightRadius = CGSize(width: rightRadius, height: rightRadius)
        
        maskPath = UIBezierPath(shouldRoundRect: bounds, topLeftRadius: topLeftRadius, topRightRadius: topRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius: bottomLeftRadius, bottomRightRadius: bottomRightRadius, indentFromLeft: 0, indentFromRight: indentFromRight)
    }
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
    layer.mask = shape
    
}
```

}

TableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {return 0}
    return structMessagesArr[section - 1].messages.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return structMessagesArr.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "currentChatCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrentChatCell
    
    let message = structMessagesArr[indexPath.section - 1].messages[indexPath.row]
    cell.messageLabel.text = message.body
    let sender = message.sender
    
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    if sender == currentAuthUser.ID {
        
        let view = cell.messageBubble as! testView
        view.currentUser = true
        view.label.text = cell.messageLabel.text
        view.label.font = cell.messageLabel.font
        
        if message.messagedWritingOnServer {cell.statusMessage.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark")}
        if message.messageRead {cell.statusMessage.image = UIImage(named: "MessageSend")}
        if message.messageLike {cell.statusMessage.image = UIImage(named: "LikeMessageRed")}
        
        cell.statusMessage.isHidden = false
        cell.heartView.isHidden = true
        cell.avatar.image = UIImage()
        cell.messageBubble.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "CurrentUserMessageColor")

        cell.messageLabel.textAlignment = .right
        cell.messageLabel.textColor = .white
```

Comment: I highly recommend that you learn about auto-layout and constraints - it will make it much easier to handle sizing. However, for now, don't put that code in `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` ... instead, move it all to `override func layoutSubviews()` -- that *might* be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by having each redraw the cell view in preparation before reusing

PrepeareforReuse(){

setNeedsDisplay()

}